# Google Sheets script - Add a new row when a checkbox is ticked and a conditional requirement

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Very new to coding, but looking for a little help.  I have a Google Sheet spreadsheet I am developing and I want to add some functionality to a checkbox.  I want a new line to be inserted after the line with the checkbox that has the same Date, checkbox checked, and Caregiver Name as the line that was checked, but the Staff column will always be a specific person (in the example it would always be 'Staff ABC, Supervisor').

Additionally, if the checkbox is checked and the Staff is already 'Staff ABC, Supervisor', a new line will NOT be created.

In the image below, the checkbox in Row 4 should automatically create Row 5.  Row 5 should be filled out exactly as it is in the image, but since the Staff is the supervisor, I don't want that checkbox to create a new row.  New row does not need to be in yellow, I just formatted it that way to draw attention to what I'm trying to achieve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtPvK.png)

I searched on stack overflow and google for some samples of how to do something similar to this, I found some examples of bound scripts to create in Google sheets, but I'm struggling to make it work for this example.  As mentioned above I am very new to coding in general.

Here is where I'm at so far.  I am getting a getRange not defined error.  I'm pretty new to this so it's just taking me a long time to diagnose how to fix what likely is something very simple.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var checkbox = sheet.getActiveRange().getValue();
  var selectedRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var selectedStaff = sheet.getRange(selectedRow,2).getValue();

  //Run if selected cell has a checkbox and ticked
  while(checkbox == true){
    addValues(selectedRow, sheet, selectedStaff);
    break;
  }
}

//Function to process values based on checkmark being ticked
function addValues(selectedRow, sheet, selectedStaff){

  if(selectedStaff != "Staff ABC, Supervisor"){
//Insert a new row after the ticked checkbox, setup the 
staff to be Staff ABC, Suupervisor. Session start and end 
times and telehealth should be blank.
    sheet.appendRow([getRange(selectedRow,1).getValue(),"Staff 
    ABC,Supervisor","","","","",getRange(selectedRow,7).getValue(),""])
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1).setValue(sheet.getRange(Sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValue()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),6).insertCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

Comment: Two things: 1) please try to include sample data in your questions. It is expected as a matter of course. 2) if you have an error message, please include the exact wording of the error message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close to what you wish:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate");
    let lr = getColumnHeight(1, sh, e.source);
    sh.insertRowAfter(lr)
    const [b,,,,,g] = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2,1,6).getValues().flat();
    let rules = e.range.offset(0, -3, 1, 3).getDataValidations();
    sh.getRange(lr + 1, 3, 1, 3).setDataValidations(rules);
    sh.getRange(lr + 1, 2).setValue(b);
    sh.getRange(lr + 1, 7).setValue(g);
    sh.getRange(lr + 1, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy"));
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Helper Function:

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()) { rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Demo:

[image]